# How to increment in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let userScore = document.getElementById('userScore')
userScore = 0
if (whichOne == "rock" && compImg.src == imgArray[2].src) {
  console.log('win')
  userScore + 1
}
```

```html
<h4>User:</h4>
<div id='userScore'> </div>
```

The increment does not work, I tried userscore++ also but no luck. The console.log does work though. Where is my problem?

Comment: Is `userScore` supposed to be the DIV or a number?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the text content of an element?

Comment: After you do `userScore++;` you need to display its value somewhere.

Comment: Should I do, userScore.innerHTML = userScore first?

Comment: Storing values in DOM is generally a bad practice. The above code also redefines variable `userScore`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment a number that's shown in a DIV, you have to first get that value into the `userScore` variable with `.innerText`. Then assign it back after adding 1.

```js
let scoreDiv = document.getElementById('userScore')
let userScore = parseInt(scoreDiv.innerText);
if (whichOne == "rock" && compImg.src == imgArray[2].src) {
  console.log('win');
  scoreDiv.innerText = userScore + 1;
}
```

```html
<h4>User:</h4>
<div id='userScore'>0</div>
```